# configure image sensor device on i2c bus in linux

Tags: linux, module, driver, yocto, i2c

I need to configure the registers (register address - 16 bits) of image sensor residing on the i2c-2 bus. I am using i2ctools commands (i2cset,i2cget etc.) from the command line to configure other hardware devices (register address - 8 bits).

i2ctools only allow register address ranging from 0x00 to 0xFF.

Can anbody suggest any alternate approach to configure this image sensor.
My need is only to configure the registers on board start up (one time initialize). I am using linux built using yocto on my board.

What is the proper way to configure the registers of any hardware device if its just a one time requirement after start up ?

I did some research online, do i need to write kernel module or kernel driver for this. What is the difference between the two - module and driver ?
How to implement the same in yocto ?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a kernel driver or module for this.

```
i2cset [-f] [-y] [-r] i2cbus chip-address data-address [value] ... [mode]
```

mode must be `w` for 16 bit data-address.

Comment: I tried with this example i2cset -f -y -r 2 0x20 0x3120 0x00D1 w but i am getting this Error: Data address invalid!
Usage: i2cset [-f] [-y] [-m MASK] [-r] I2CBUS CHIP-ADDRESS DATA-ADDRESS [VALUE] ... [MODE]
  I2CBUS is an integer or an I2C bus name
  ADDRESS is an integer (0x03 - 0x77)
  MODE is one of:
    c (byte, no value)
    b (byte data, default)
    w (word data)
    i (I2C block data)
    s (SMBus block data)
    Append p for SMBus PEC

Comment: Sorry, word mode is for value not for data-address - my fault.
You can try i2ctranser:
i2ctransfer 2 w4@0x20 0x31 0x20 0x00 0xD1

(i2c bus 2, write 4 bytes to device at bus address 0x20)

Comment: i2ctransfer command is not found on my system. I found solution, im able to set using i2cset -y 2 0x20 0x31 0x20 0x00 0xD1 i